# How to retrieve the entire HTML tag with Gecko in C#?

Tags: c#, gecko

Purpose of the question:

I need to display to the end user, the incorrect HTML tags. For example, take the  tag.
        If there is no "alt" attribute, i have to display the entire tag 
(

```
<img src="blahblah.jpg"/>
```

).

```
    My attempt:

    Skybound.Gecko.GeckoElementCollection elemcol=wbMain.Document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    foreach(Skybound.Gecko.GeckoElement elem in elemcol)
    {
//Just a basic check to see if the attribute exists
    if((elem.GetAttribute("alt").ToString())==null)
    {
    String content=elem.InnerHtml;
    return content;
    }
    }
```

elem.InnerHtml just returns a null value. I need to get the entire tag.. More like outerHTML.. But outerHTML command is not supported here. I am new to c# and am really not able to get through with it. Please help me with it. :(

Answer (score 0):

`outerHTML` is supported in Gecko [since version 11](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.outerHTML). Does Skybound support this version yet?